# overwrite the header of a file without copying the whole file

Tags: linux, command-line

Asuming I have two files, one large file and one small file, I want to write the smaller file to the large file without overwriting the remaining part of the larger file.

Both are binary files, and the large file can become very large, so I want to avoid copying the whole file, as that will take some time. Is there any standard Linux console utility to do this, or do I need to write it myself?

Comment: maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365/prepend-to-a-file-one-liner-shell

Comment: @Wimmel, Shouldn't this be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will overwrite the beginning of `large-file` with the contents of `small-file`:

```
dd if=small-file of=large-file conv=notrunc
```

Comment: Also see http://www.rationallyparanoid.com/articles/dd-hex-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but you can use `cat`:

```
cat smallfile >> largefile
```

This will append `smallfile` to `largefile`.

Comment: smallfile needs to be at the beginning of largefile, not at the end.